# How to register Consul Agent Installed on K8 Cluster with External Consul Server (non-k8 cluster).

Tags: kubernetes, consul

We have installed only consul agents on k8 cluster using the helm charts.

https://www.consul.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm.html

We have a separate consul server installed on a cluster (this is non-k8 cluster) outside my k8 cluster.

Is it possible to join my agents to the consul server cluster (non-k8 cluster)?

I have checked the below link

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/cloud-auto-join.html#tag_value-1

However, this describes only about joining the consul agent joining to the existing k8 consul server.

```
consul agent -retry-join "provider=k8s label_selector=\"app=consul,component=server\""
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using [`client.join`](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-client-join) parameter in values file since we are using same setup - consul cluster running outside k8s. Consul-k8s is running in client only mode by setting [`server.enabled`](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-server-enabled) to false.